# LibGDX - Drawing an Equilateral Triangle

Tags: java, math, libgdx, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to make an equilateral triangle using LibGDX libraries, but I am not the best at geometry / trigonometry. I got really close, but one side is too long and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

The points are relative to the center of the shape.

```
    shapeX[0] = x + MathUtils.cos(radians) * Variables.lineLength;
    shapeY[0] = y + MathUtils.sin(radians) * Variables.lineLength;

    shapeX[1] = x + MathUtils.cos(radians - 4 * Variables.pi / (Variables.pi * 2)) * Variables.lineLength;
    shapeY[1] = y + MathUtils.sin(radians - 4 * Variables.pi / (Variables.pi * 2)) * Variables.lineLength;

    shapeX[2] = x + MathUtils.cos(radians + 4 * Variables.pi / (Variables.pi * 2)) * Variables.lineLength;
    shapeY[2] = y + MathUtils.sin(radians + 4 * Variables.pi / (Variables.pi * 2)) * Variables.lineLength;
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding 4.25 to the radians instead of 4, but I am not sure why it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2pi radians in a circle.  To get an equilateral n-sided polygon, divide 2pi into n pieces: (2/n)pi. The polygon vertices will fall at i(2/n)pi for i = 0,1,...(n-1). Since you have n = 3, you want 0*2/3pi = 0pi, 1*2/3pi = 2/3pi, and 2*2/3pi = 4/3pi.  But it's probably easier to use a loop than to hard code these values.

Also, if you want the edges to have your given `linelength`, you must scale by sqrt(3)/3 to find the radius. Why? The length of a side of an equilateral triangle circumscribed by the unit circle is 3/sqrt(3), so scale the radius by the inverse to get sides of unit length. Wrapping all this up,

```
double radius = Math.sqrt(3) / 3 * Variables.lineLength;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  double theta = 2 * Math.PI / 3 * i;
  shapeX[i] = x + radius * MathUtils.cos(theta);
  shapeY[i] = y + radius * MathUtils.sin(theta);
}
```

Note this puts the first vertex on the positive x-axis. To rotate the polygon, add the desired offset to `theta`.  For example to have the first vertex on the positive y-axis, use pi/2.